# Getting started with Websphere portal 6.1 

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, portal

Okay, my company is a bank. The upper management is dead set on a websphere IBM portal. Apparently IBM is tossing them a bone they can't refuse. We're also a very big IBM shop anyhow with A LOT of LotusNotes applications.

In my experience with IBM, they generally make you go through them to learn their stuff. I'm having to sort of jump in head first so that I can give an overview of the product to the development team. I'm specifically trying to find free portal development resources. Heck a hello world portal would be fine. Also, when I say portal, this also includes portlets.

Another issue is that I learn best by doing. Can someone point me to a freetrial link or something for websphere portal? Really, I just need anything that will let me get my feet wet with the sort of coding that I'll need to do for the actual portal.

Thoughts, comments, suggestions are all welcome in any way/shape/form.

Comment: Let me be the first to offer my condolences for having to use Portal6.1. Just be thankful it's not 5.1...

Answer (score 2):

Check out the IBM [Redbooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/portals/websphere) and [online help](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc.html) for documentation and development guides. Try the [Rational Application Developer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/rad/) trial for portlet development - this comes with a WPS test server.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right from the days I worked with it, RAD have some sample "hello world" projects for WPS. 
You can also [import sample portlets from here](http://www.skywayradio.com/tech/WAS51/portal/wps/wpsbscfg.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me, these two are very good CMS solutions:

- Liferay
- Alfresco

Liferay is an open source Portal based on Java. It has payed solutions. 
Alfresco is only a CMS solution but it has social applications and many nice content management features.

To be honest, I've tested both Liferay and WebSphere Portal (I am a certified admin). Liferay seems more appealing at first but it lacks a couple of features (At least the versions I tred) that will slow you down in the middle of the deployment. It doesnt have many portlets from start (You will have to develop them)

Also, if you are planning on making a site that relies heavily on customization and personalization, Liferay doesnt have that much support.

WepSphere portal also have much better support for SSO (Single Sign On) and the security is better (Since you are a bank)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a IBM WebSphere Portal Express 60 day trial download [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/wpe/).
IBM WebSphere Portal Express V8 offers application integration, document management, web content management and collaboration capabilities in a single, easy-to-deploy solution targeted at small and medium business. Now includes popular social capabilities, including blogs, wikis, tagging and ratings, as well as an updated configuration wizard and enhanced analytics support.